# How to access application-level middleware from router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to access my application-level middleware from router in a project generated with express application generator.

Middleware is used to query database with user ID received from router.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple (or fundamental) but can't get around the problem (this being my first Node.js project). So more than best practice I'm looking for a simple solution

I've tried using different app methods including post.

/app.js

```js
var MyAppMidW = function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(queryDB(req));
  next()
}
app.use(MyAppMidW);
```

/routes/index.js

```js
router.get("/dbquery", (req, res) => {
  if (req.header('auth-header')) {
    res.send(req.app.get.MyAppMidW(req.header('auth-header'))); //The problem
  }
  else {
    res.send(req.app.get('defaultData')); //This works
  }
});
```

Error messages include "$middleware is not a function" and "$middleware is not defined".

#### Solution

/app.js

```js
app.MyAppMidW = function (req) {
  queryDB(req);
}
```

/routes/index.js

```js
router.get("/dbquery", (req, res) => {
  if (req.header('auth-header')) {
    req.app.MyAppMidW(req.header('auth-header'))); //Makes a database query
    res.send(req.app.get('defaultData')); //Fetches database query result
  }
  else {
    res.send(req.app.get('defaultData'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Based on your solution, wouldn't this not be middleware? It is simply a function that takes in the auth header. It wouldn't need to be `app.MyAppMidW`, you could define it in a file and import it into the route that needs into (`var MyAppMidW = require('./MyAppMidW');`)

Comment: Possibly. Original scope was changed so it is hard to say for me. Also this function has other dependencies in the app.js. My usage of the term is not very accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `app.set("MyAppMidW", MyAppMidW)` and then you can use get. Or do this inside the app.js file

```
app.MyAppMidW = function (req, res, next) {
  res.send(queryDB(req));
  next()
}
```

Then call it by `req.app.get('MyAppMidW')(req.header('auth-header'))` or `req.app.MyAppMidW(req.header('auth-header'))` inside the routes file.

But middleware is called automatically when you say `app.use(MyAppMidW)` the function is called by default on each request. So no need to call it explicitly inside the router function.

Comment: Thanks! I changed app.js (app.function instead of var and app.use) to reflect your suggestion. Also I changed index.js to use "req.app.MyAppMidW(req.header('auth-header'))". However there is still error: "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Function.app.MyAppMidW (/home/site/wwwroot/app.js:122:7)"

I'll try to troubleshoot further.

Comment: So it turns out removing unnecessary parameters from app.MyAppMidW fixed this. Also separating database query (using this) and query result fetch (using app.get).

Answer (score 2):

If you do it like this

```
     app.use(MyAppMidW);
```

Every request will query your db, and thats not what you want. I guess you use the MVC design pattern.

In your route folder you have something like this:

```
  import appController from "../controllers/app.js"
  router.get("/dbquery", appController.MyAppQuery)
```

And in your `controllers` folder you have your logic that querys the db

```
  exports.MyAppQuery = (req, res){
     //If u use mongodb for example
    YourModel.find().then(data => {
       res.json(data)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a thought. I had no design pattern in mind. FYI for database I'm using Azure Cosmos DB with Core SQL API

Comment: Here i have found something https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos you will need to put your query code into your controller logic for querys